# How to avoid the AUTOINCREMENT keyword with EFC and SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

[AUTOINCREMENT doesn't usually need to be used in SQLite.](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) Even without this keyword, automatically generated IDs work.

However, integer primary key is declared as AUTOINCREMENT when using Entity Framework Core (as of 2.1.3) and SQLite. Is there a way to avoid this?

I tried adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute to the entity's primary key property, but this disables automatic key generation altogether and I have to set it manually for each insert. Otherwise, EFC tries to insert with an explicit `Id = 0`.

So I need it to be treated as database generated on insert, I'd just like to avoid the unnecessary AUTOINCREMENT keyword. Is there a way to do this?

#### Edit

Here's some example C# code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Experiments
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=temp.sqlite");
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will create a database that looks like this, when viewed with DB Browser for SQLite:

[image]

I'd rather not have the primary key declared as AUTOINCREMENT, which also creates the sqlite_sequence table. SQLite can generate keys without that keyword, and it does it simpler and faster.

Comment: Glancing through the entity framework docs, I don't think it's possible short of writing your own custom backend instead of using the standard sqlite one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the issue is caused by the following code in the current [`SqliteMigrationsAnnotationProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.Sqlite.Core/Migrations/Internal/SqliteMigrationsAnnotationProvider.cs#L54) class:

```
if (property.ValueGenerated == ValueGenerated.OnAdd
    && property.ClrType.UnwrapNullableType().IsInteger()
    && !HasConverter(property))
{

    yield return new Annotation(SqliteAnnotationNames.Autoincrement, true);
}
```

which is forcing the [`SqliteMigrationsSqlGenerator`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.Sqlite.Core/Migrations/SqliteMigrationsSqlGenerator.cs) class to [include `AUTOINCREMENT`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.2/src/EFCore.Sqlite.Core/Migrations/SqliteMigrationsSqlGenerator.cs#L463).

I don't know why is that, I would assume it's a leftover bug, but you'd better ask in their issue tracker.

Looking at the code, looks like setting fake value converter will prevent that and can be used as temporary workaround:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
    .Property(e => e.Id)
    .HasConversion(v => v, v => v);
```

Comment: Thanks for the research. It's could be there by design, since it does make things behave more like in a traditional database. Though I wonder why they would make value converters have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Defined the model class as below. So you will not map the Id column and use another column as PK.

```
[NotMapped]
public override int Id
{
    get
    {
        return PKColumn;
    }
    set
    {
        PKColumn = value;
    }
}

[Key]
public virtual int PKColumn { get; set; }
```

Comment: This doesn't change the schema, it just sets the name of the primary key column to PKColumn.

Comment: @relatively_random you need to remove the code for autogenerated identity, if you have in DBContext for this entity..then add migration and run update-database command

Comment: I don't understand. What code for autogenerated identity?

Comment: @relatively_random can you post the DBCONTEXT